# Simple type theory: equational axioms validated by biCartesian closed categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, type-theory

In this question, we consider only type theories with no ground types and no function symbols.

I want to know whether there exists a model of simple type theory with finite products, finite coproducts, and exponentials which is not a Heyting (pre)algebra, and validates some equational axioms peculiar to that model.

First, for simple type theory with finite products and finite coproducts, its models are categories with finite products and finite coproducts which are not necessarily distributive. (Here, “simple” means “neither polymorphic nor dependent”.) Lacking distributivity of finite products over finite coproducts, the elimination rules for $0$ and $+$ needs to be the following:
$$
\frac{\Gamma \vdash M : 0}{\Gamma \vdash \mathrm{elim}(M) : A}
\\
\frac{\Gamma \vdash M : A + B \hspace{20px} x : A \vdash N_1 : C \hspace{20px} y : B \vdash N_2 : C}{\Gamma \vdash \mathrm{case}(M, x. N_1, y. N_2) : C}
$$
Terms $N_1$ and $N_2$ cannot refer to variables in $\Gamma$.
There are two models for such type theory: the category Set of sets and (total) functions, and the category Pfn of sets and partial functions. The former is a [distributive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive%20category) and the latter is not.
Being distributive implies the second projection $A \times 0 \to 0$ is an isomorphism for any $A$.
Thus, considering equational theory of the type theory, we have an equational axiom:
$$
x : A \times 0 \vdash \mathrm{elim} (\mathrm{snd} (x)) = x : A \times 0
$$
where $\mathrm{elim}$ is an elimination form for $0$ and $\mathrm{snd}$ is the second projection,
which is validated by Set, but not by Pfn.

Now, we add exponentials to the type theory so that its models become [BiCartesian Closed Categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicartesian+closed+category) (BiCCC). Since BiCCC is always a distributive category, we cannot reproduce the above discussion. (Also, Pfn is not a BiCCC.)
We can see that every Heyting (pre)algebra is a BiCCC, so we have an equational axiom like:
$$
x : A \times A \vdash \mathrm{fst} (x) = \mathrm{snd} (x) : A
$$
where $\mathrm{fst}$ is the first projection, because each Heyting (pre)algebra has Hom propositions rather than Hom sets when viewed as a category. Such an axiom is of course not valid in general models.
Then, my question is whether there exists a model (BiCCC) of simple type theory with finite products, finite coproducts, and exponentials which validates non-theorem equations between terms, and is not a Heyting (pre)algebra.

**EDIT**: Maybe I should have asked “is there any BiCCC relative to which the equational theory is *incomplete* with the proviso that it is not a Heyting (pre)algebra?”

Comment: What precisely do you mean by *fibred* finite coproducts?  I would understand that to mean that (categorically) the natural map $A \times \coprod_i B_i \to A' \times \coprod_i B_i$ is always an iso. But then the case with $A' = 1$ and the 0-ary co-product gives that $A \times 0 \simeq 0$ — and more generally, this sense of *fibred coproducts* implies distributivity, which it seems you don’t want.

Comment: No ground types? How do you even write down any type at all?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Finite products (presumably) include $1$, and then finite coprodcts give you all finite sets. The topos of finite sets seems to answer the question, since it validates the law of the excluded middle.

Comment: That makes sense, and presumably we get $0$ as well. I am not sure about the answer, because the OP seems to be asking for an equation expressed in the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus without any term and type constants, only metavariables denoting types are allowed. But maybe we can still express excluded middle as a rule of inference?

Comment: @efk: could you be a bit more precise what you mean by “axiom”? Must it be an equality? If not, then Andreas Blass's suggestion works, because the axiom could essentially postulate the existence of a term of type $A + (A \to 0)$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes, it must be an equality between terms.

Comment: I would imagine every expressible type in this simple type theory without ground types is isomorphic to a finite copower 1 + 1 + ... + 1, and thus imposing any equation which does not already hold amounts to imposing an equation between two elements of 1 + 1 + ... + 1 which does not already hold. Which can then be exploited to make the two elements of 1 + 1 equal, which can then be exploited to make all elements of all types equal, giving us a preorder.

Comment: @SridharRamesh thank you. Your argument is plausible but I’m not sure yet.

Comment: Now I think I’m sure. Later I’ll write an answer myself.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine I’d used the term “fibred finite coproducts” to mean the following thing. A fibred coproduct of A and B over $\Gamma$ is an object X and two morphisms $p : \Gamma \times A \to X$ and $q : \Gamma \times B \to X$ such that given another object Y and two morphisms $p’, q’$ with the same domain but the codomain being Y, there exists a unique $f : \Gamma \times X \to Y$ such that $fp = p’$ and $fq = q’$. But I found that this concept is essentially the same thing with distributive coproducts, so I edited my question not to use fibred finite coproducts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SridharRamesh, it turned out that no such model exists so I present a proof sketch. All mistakes are mine.

In the equational theory of our simple type theory, every type is isomorphic to a type of the form 1 + 1 + … + 1, which we call a finite copower. Then imposing a non-theorem equation on terms of any type amounts to imposing one on terms of a finite copower. Any non-theorem equation on a finite copower necessarily identifies 2 distinct inhabitants of that type.

In a model, identifying 2 distinct inhabitants of $\Sigma_n 1$, where $n \ge 3$, gives rise to identifying the 2 distinct inhabitants of 1 + 1, which in turn makes 1 and 1 + 1 isomorphic. So every object denoted by some type becomes isomorphic to 0 or 1, therefore(?) any model validating a non-theorem equation must be either $\{0 \le 1\}$ or $\{\star\}$, up to equivalence of categories.

**EDIT**: Although not interesting, I believe every full subcategory of Set whose objects are the empty set, the singleton set, an infinite set $X$, $X^X$, $X^{(X^X)}$, $(X^X)^X$, and so on is a BiCCC which is not a Heyting prealgebra.